# For how long can you wear a surgical mask?

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology, face-mask-respirator

I used to think that you can wear a mask for up to two hours, regardless of how many times you put it on and take it off. [This](https://www.nccn.org/covid-19/pdf/Guidance_for_Patient_Use_of_Medical_Face_Mask.pdf) guide says you can wear it for up to five times without any specifications on a time limit. So if I want to stretch the use of a mask for as long as possible, what should I do? I suppose there are some limits on both how much time it's on your face in total and the number of times you put it on.

Comment: I don't know how they came up with 5 times. That sounds rather arbitrary to me, particularly since the CDC [can't put a firm number of the reuse of N95 masks](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/hcwcontrols/recommendedguidanceextuse.html). So I think this is likely an opinion-based question.